Today is a prime!
Today, 20240603 already in some parts of the world, is a prime number. Just twenty-one other dates during 2024 are also primes.
In what year will there be none?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488712/is-there-a-prime-every-year-if-yyyymmdd-is-treated-as-a-base-10-number suggests the smallest year is the year 27789755

@BeastlyGerbil According to a comment by nickgard at that link, the first nonprime year is actually 13446204.

...empirically, there is no solution for the format YYYYMMDD.

Here is a year when there definitely will be none

 $10000!$

Because

 For each  $2 \leq n \leq 10000$, $10000! + n$ is divisible by $n$.
 More importantly, $10000(10000!) + n$ is also divisible by $n$ and so, not prime.
 Since $10000(10000!) + 1$ does not constitute a meaningful date, we don't have to worry about that and all other dates will be covered.

A smaller example

 Given that we only have to worry about factors less than or equal to $1231$ we can say the same about the year $1231!$
 In fact we could consider a year which is just given by the product of all possible MMDD date combinations which is again much smaller.


(And instead of the product we could use the LCM...)

@mathmandan Yes, indeed!

Using the time-honored tactic of hoping my code finishes before the heat-death of the universe, it appears that the first year that meets this criteria is:

 8153391

I found this with this rudimentary python script, which prints the year each time a new minimum number of prime dates within the year is found:

This script uses the sympy library, which has a function to return all primes within a given range. Feel free to mock my poor python skills in the comments!

     import sympy

     def is_date(number):
       day_count_for_month = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

       day = int(number % 100)
       number = (number - day) / 100
       month = int(number % 100)
       year = int((number - month) / 100)

       if year%4==0 and (year%100 != 0 or year%400==0):
         day_count_for_month[2] = 29

       return (1 <= month and month <= 12 and 1 <= day and day <= day_count_for_month[month])

     best = 100
     i = 2024
     found = False

     while not found:
       primes = filter(is_date,sympy.primerange(10000 * i, 10000*i + 1231))
       length = len(list(primes))

       if length < best:
         print(i)
         print(length)
         print()
         best = length

       if length == 0:
         found = True

       i = i + 1


I forgot to have the script print timestamps, so I'm not sure exactly how long it took, but it was between 6 and 18 hours.
